# Report viewer control Export function exposes session id with ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

The file Export function from report viewer control uses session id in its url, like heightlighted below:

```
http://website/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=sessionidXXXXXXXXX&Culture=2057&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=2057&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=2c3de8dad69842d7bed6bd7b755784bb&OpType=Export&FileName=FileNameToExport&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=CSV
```

User clicks `Export -> required file format -> file downloaded -> the link` above is for the file downloaded.

Please see the image below

http://s23.postimg.org/8yb71b7dn/Untitled.png

I want to find out if the session id will expose security risk. If so, if it is possible to remove the session id from url, or a more secure way to allow download.

Please note that this is reporting services client side that sends requrest from web forms to reporting services.

I tried setting `UseSessionCookies` to false, but still not working.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934303.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UseSessionCookies` should be set to **true** (default value), not false - but it won't help you if the browser has cookies disabled (session id will be forced in the url).

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some confusion about which sessionID this refers to, the SSRS sessionId or the asp.net sessionID. According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid(v=vs.110).aspx), using the asp.net sessionId in the URL is a potential security risk:

> The SessionID is sent between the server and the browser in clear
>   text, either in a cookie or in the URL. As a result, an unwanted
>   source could gain access to the session of another user by obtaining
>   the SessionID value and including it in requests to the server. If you
>   are storing private or sensitive information in session state, it is
>   recommended that you use SSL to encrypt any communication between the
>   browser and server that includes the SessionID.

The most common alternative would be to keep the sessionId out of the URL by enabling cookies. [You can check whether cookies are enabled or not by using the isCookieless method of the sessionstate element and set it using the cookieless attribute.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.iscookieless(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, it looks to me like this is a reporting services session Id, because the asp.net session ID is a 20 character string and is referenced like this:
    (S(4danlfat035muve4g0mvgfrr))

Whereas the Reporting services session id is referenced in the sessionID=x way that you have listed in your url, and is basically used to avoid re-rendering the report everytime a small change is made to it, or an export is made. You should be able to safely drop the sessionID altogether, and reporting services will simply create a new session and re-render the report. This will be a bit more of a strain on resources. [More info on SSRS sessions.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155081(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Is there an innate way to drop it with the control?  Or will I have to write an intercept on the request?